# How to replicate Finder Smart Folders

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, spotlight

I am looking to replicate the smart folder feature of the finder which show:
- files modified in during the day
- Files modified teh day before
- All images files
- All movies files
...

I know it is using spotlight but what are the queries behind this?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a search query in the finder and save it as a smart folder. The “folder” can then be opened in a text editor – it’s an XML file containing the Spotlight query and additional semantic data describing the search window.

Comment: I've been trying to modify these XML files to do things like use multiple folders for their search scope but haven't had any luck... any idea where I could find some documentation on this?